# Permanent group in xmpp

Tags: c#, xmpp, multiuserchat, agsxmpp

I am developing a chat app in c#.net using jabber, agsxmpp library and I want to make groupchat in it such as whatsapp groupchat and skype groupchat.

I came across **persistent room** in xmpp.
Does it provides the functionality of permanent groups? and is it possible for a creator of the persistent group **to add members without sending invites** to them?

I searched the XMPP stuff on google, but nothing found clearly which room to use persistent, or should go with members only? if yes then please explain how.

Answer (score 1):

XMPP groupchat is defined in [XEP-0045: Multi-User Chat](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0045.html). The specification indeed define "Persistent Room", as "A room that is not destroyed if the last occupant exits; antonym: Temporary Room.".

I think however this is not what you mean as you refer to Whatsapp. In XMPP, MUC room are based on presence. It means you can only be in a MUC room if you have a session open and sent your presence to join the MUC Room. You cannot force a user to join a MUC room as only his client can send the presence to join.